# How to retrieve files from google drive using C# on visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

can anyone please guide me on the methods and classes that i need to put in my web application on visual studio 2010 that allows me to retrieve the file from Google drive? I have only designed the layout. The layout look something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot upload the layout as i have not enough reputation points,do you mind if i send you the file to your private email?

Comment: Have you checked the Google Drive API [download sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#examples)? There is a .NET version and seems straightforward.

Comment: I need to display the file in various textboxes, is it possible to do so?